# How to view and record the user's tablet?

Tags: usability-testing

I need to conduct a remote user interview, while they are using a tablet.

I'm looking for a way to see what the user is doing in a tablet, and also record the conversation and the user's tablet screen.

I'd appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Since this is likely to come down to platform-specific app recommendations, could you say what tablet/OS they will be using?

Comment: this would be for iPad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that since you didn't add any platform details that you're looking for something that works on desktop, iOS and Android? If that's correct, you may want to look into Lookback at https://lookback.io/features/live/.

It's a live link that shows you the user's screen, the user's face, while conducting a live conversation. Desktop also allows multiple observers, which is handy for note-taking and group reviews.

It's built for user testing, and while I haven't used it in production, the 14-day evaluation was promising. I'd recommend you give it a try and see if it works for your mysterious purposes. :)